# Authenticate in Lotus Notes on localhost

Tags: authentication, localhost, lotus-notes

This might sound a little complicated, but as I'm often working on my local databases in Lotus Notes I got the problem, that I can not authenticate. So I'm always working as Anonymous on my database.

The Problem is, that I can not test all functions, because for that I would need a valid Notesname.

How can I authenticate on localhost to work with my name/account and not as Anonymous?

Comment: Where are you connecting from? The Notes client or Java for instance?

Comment: That's what I'm doing: Open the database in Notes Designer. Click Preview of the database in Browser. Open the database in Firefox with this path: http://localhost/Development/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp

Comment: IBM has never enabled authenticated access through the preview feature that is built into the client. They would have to have a full Domino Directory and other server configuration databases in the client installation for that to happen.  They figure that you might as well just install a local server for that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not authenticate XPages/web applicatons using the local HTTP preview. You need to install a local server to do that (which is a good thing anyway for XPages development).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I try to discuss this with my Notes Admin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to your machine using the fully qualified domain name, e.g. ^http://mymachine.mydomain.com instead of localhost

Comment: That didn't work. I tried it with the FQDN in front, but I get the error: Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Access Denied Exception

Answer (score 0):

You can add yourself to your local address-book. And have it added to Database Security as Manager or whatever you want. That will help you to login using HTTP for local database.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to also do this, and I recalled a tip from searchdomino.com, the poster is Shawn Dezego
http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Testing-Authentication-Authorization-in-a-Web-App-Locally-WIthout-Running-a-Domino-Server

Here's the gist:

> Just create any groups in your local address book and add your name to
>   the proper groups, roles etc. Then go to your Domains public address
>   book (Domino Directory), copy your person doc and paste it in your
>   local NAB. That's it.

This is the same basic tip as offered by the adjacent commenter. However, I think this may not work for Xpages apps, so I am loading a local server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a person document in local NAB (names.nsf) and add HTTPpassword field with your password (hash it using `@password("mypassword")` formula) as text.

Make sure the person document contains the Fullname field, where you can put as test list your aliases. But Notes will use the first field entry as your name.

And remeber to set the first entry in canonical way (`cn=user/ou=organization/o=domain`)

Now you are ready to use this name in ACLs and names' (nested) groups.

I suggest to use hosts file to remap localhost with your site domain.

Enjoy!

(P.S. : You need to add anonymous entry in your db's ACL, and set it to editor access level. Once opened the application with browser, use the url command "&login" to force Notes to authenticate you)